# Marginal Likelihood optimization with python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy-optimize-minimize, gaussian-process

I'm trying to optimize the marginal likelihood to estimate parameters for a Gaussian process regression.
So i defined the marginal log likelihood this way:

```
def marglike(par,X,Y):
l,sigma_n = par
n = len(X)
dist_X = (X.T - X)**2
k = np.exp(-(1/(2*(l**2)))*dist_X)
inverse = np.linalg.inv(k + (sigma_n**2)*np.eye(len(k))) 
ml = (1/2)*np.dot(np.dot(Y.T,inverse),Y) + (1/2)*np.log(np.linalg.det(k + (sigma_n**2)*np.eye(len(k)))) + (n/2)*np.log(2*np.pi)
return ml
```

Where the parameter to be optimized are " l " and " sigma_n ".
With some initial values and data, the function give some value back:

```
X = np.linspace(1,10,20)
F = np.sin(X)
start = np.array([1,0.05]) #initial parameters values

marglike(start,X,F)

marglike(start,X,F)
Out[75]: array([[1872.6511786]])
```

But when i try to optimize the parameters with " minimize ", i get this:

```
re = minimize(marglike,start,args=(X,F),method="BFGS",options = {'disp':True})

re = minimize(marglike,start,args=(X,F),method="BFGS",options = {'disp':True})
Optimization terminated successfully.
     Current function value: 22.863446
     Iterations: 8
     Function evaluations: 60
     Gradient evaluations: 15

re.x
Out[89]: array([1.        , 0.70845989])
```

I dont know why but the parameter "l" don't seem to be optimized, but it matches the starting value that i fixed.

Any suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reshape `X` to 2d first for `X.T-X` to work. Also, you need to add one more parameter called variance (`var` in the code below) in optimization. Let me know if the below code solves your problem.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def marglike(par,X,Y):
  # print(par)
  l,var,sigma_n = par
  n = len(X)
  dist_X = (X - X.T)**2
  # print(dist_X)
  k = var*np.exp(-(1/(2*(l**2)))*dist_X)
  inverse = np.linalg.inv(k + (sigma_n**2)*np.eye(len(k))) 
  ml = (1/2)*np.dot(np.dot(Y.T,inverse),Y) + (1/2)*np.log(np.linalg.det(k + (sigma_n**2)*np.eye(len(k)))) + (n/2)*np.log(2*np.pi)
  return ml

X = np.linspace(1,10,20).reshape(-1,1) # Reshaping
F = np.sin(X)
start = np.array([1.1,1.6,0.05]) #initial parameters values
print(marglike(start,X,F))

re = minimize(marglike,start,args=(X,F),method="L-BFGS-B",options = {'disp':True})
re.x
```

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for answering.
The code seems to work this way.
Regarding the new parameter "var", i avoided to put it in since it is possible to calculate it by closed form (Surrogates by Robert B. Gramacy). 
Once i put in in the formula, shouldn't i square it ? (as done for "l" and "sigma_n")

Comment: And also, the result for sigma_n is a negative value, and since it is a variance, how this is possible ?

Comment: I did not know if it's possible to calculate var in closed form. Thanks for letting me know, can you guide me to the resource where I can know how to do that exactly. If we want to interpret var as variance, no need to square, but if as a standard deviation (sigma) we need to square it. Now, about sigma_n being negative, we need to set the bound in minimize method to avoid this. Generally, I have seen bounds of (10^-5, 10^5) but setting it positive should also work

Comment: Ah ok i think i got it, so for the same logic i should remove the squared form for sigma_n and l ?!
Regarding the closed form, you can check this book:

Surrogates
Gaussian Process Modeling, Design, and
Optimization for the Applied Sciences

by Robert B. Gramacy

If you can't find it, i can provide it for you!

Comment: No, we should not remove the square, if we want to sustain how sigma_n (noise), l (lengthscale), and sigma_f (standard deviation) are interpreted in the community. Though I am not sure, I think square also helps in gradient calculation in optimization. I would say refer to the well-known library GPy and dive into source code. Thanks a lot for the book. It looks amazing for applied sciences !!